# Not able to convert char[] as list in java

Tags: java

What went wrong here?

```
    String st = "String";
    char[] chArr = st.toCharArray();
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(chArr));

    // Converting array to list
    List<Character> stArrList = Arrays.asList(chArr); //Throwing error

    // String array
    String[] stringArr = { "S", "t", "r", "i", "n", "g" };
    // Converting String array to list
    List<String> stringList = Arrays.asList(stringArr);
```

While trying to convert String[] to `List<String>` using asList, it is working. But for char[] to `List<Character>` is not working.

Throwing below error:
     Type mismatch: cannot convert from `List<char[]>`  to `List<Character>`

Comment: actually what are you trying to do?

Comment: Trying to convert array to list @Prasad

Comment: native types are not objects and special rules apply.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen but why it is able to convert as List<char[]> ?

Comment: Your understanding of how Arrays.asList() work as invoked is incorrect.  It returns a list of the given arguments, not convert an array to a list.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Actually my objective is to convert Array as List. I was not sure why the Arrays.asList(CharArray) also returns List, but why it is not working. Thanks anyway.

Comment: It would if the argument was a list of objects, it isn't, it is a list of native integers.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your knowledge. Got the answer @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen

Answer (score 2):

If you look at Arrays#asList implementation it is implemented like this:

```
/**
 * Returns a fixed-size list backed by the specified array.  (Changes to
 * the returned list "write through" to the array.)  This method acts
 * as bridge between array-based and collection-based APIs, in
 * combination with {@link Collection#toArray}.  The returned list is
 * serializable and implements {@link RandomAccess}.
 *
 * <p>This method also provides a convenient way to create a fixed-size
 * list initialized to contain several elements:
 * <pre>
 *     List&lt;String&gt; stooges = Arrays.asList("Larry", "Moe", "Curly");
 * </pre>
 *
 * @param <T> the class of the objects in the array
 * @param a the array by which the list will be backed
 * @return a list view of the specified array
 */
@SafeVarargs
@SuppressWarnings("varargs")
public static <T> List<T> asList(T... a) {
    return new ArrayList<>(a);
}
```

It is important to note that it expects elements of type T where

*T is the class of the objects in the array*

The reason String[] works is because it is an array of objects, and char[] is an array of primitives

Comment: Thank you. This answered my question @EmberTraveller

Answer (score 1):

```
List<Character> stArrList = new ArrayList<Character>();
for (char c : chArr) {
        stArrList.add(c);
    }
```

Comment: I know this way of implementation. But my question was why it is not working. Thanks Anyway

Answer (score 0):

You can do,

```
st.chars().mapToObj(c -> (char) c).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

With Java 8 It is possible with a oneliner

`List<Character> stArrList = st.chars().mapToObj(c -> (char) c).collect(Collectors.toList());`

We can also use IntStream.range()  to directly access each character and add it to the list as shown below:

```
        String string = "Dinesh";

        List<Character> chars = new ArrayList<>();
        IntStream.range(0, string.length())
                .forEach(index -> chars.add(string.charAt(index)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    `String st = "String";
     String[] stringArr = st.split("");
     List<String> stringList = Arrays.asList(stringArr);
     int i=0;

     for (String c : stringList) {
            System.out.println(c);
        }`
```